# How to call saved javascript file from groovy

Tags: javascript, groovy, intellij-idea

I have javascript (.js) file and if I was to call one of the function in that file how should I do that.

I followed following steps

1. Save the file under the directory `src/test/groovy/Custom`
2. Add the directory to class path
3. Call the function from another groovy file in following way

Code

```
import Custom

getElementsByClassName("info-links")
```

But **Custom** triggers `Cannot resolve` error

Using `intelliJ 13.0.3` as my IDE
What went wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to call a JavaScript file from a Groovy class? Is `src/test/groovy/Custom` a JavaScript file? You cannot import a JavaScript file into a Groovy class.

Comment: @dpcasady `Customm ` is the directory under which I stored the javascript file `getElementsByClassName-1.0.1.js ` . How can I callesd a method in there from a `XXX.groovy ` file.